# What kind group can be realized as a Isometry group of some space?

Tags: gr.group-theory, dg.differential-geometry

Every group G is a subgroup of Isometry group of its Cayley graph.

What is essential property of  being an Isometry group? 
Lie group?

Comment: What do you mean by asking what is an essential property of being a Lie group? Every group is a Lie group (just as every set is a zero-dimensional manifold).

Comment: See also: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/993/is-every-finite-group-a-group-of-symmetries

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Every group is the full group of isometries of a connected, locally connected, complete metric space:

de Groot, J. "Groups represented by homeomorphism groups."
Math. Ann. 138 (1959) 80–102.
[MR119193](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=119193)
[doi:10.1007/BF01369667](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01369667)

Being a group of symmetries is the same thing as being a group.

You may also be interested to know that every group is the full automorphism group of a graph, not just a subgroup.  References for this and various refinements are given at [the wikipedia page for Frucht's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht%27s_theorem).

Comment: +1.  I'd been wondering if Frucht's theorem had a name for about 10 years.