# Is every finite quantum group a quantum symmetry group?

Tags: finite-groups, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

This post is basically a *quantum extension* of [Is every finite group a group of “symmetries”?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/993/34538)
Here *finite quantum group* means finite dimensional Hopf ${\rm C}^{\star}$-algebra.

[Frucht's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht%27s_theorem) states that every finite group is the automorphism group of a finite graph. Wang defined [here](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1637425) a notion of quantum automorphism group. The application to a finite space of $n$ elements is called "the quantum permutation group of $n$ symbols", and its quantum subgroups are called *quantum permutation groups* of degree $n$. Bichon introduced [here](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1937403) the quantum automorphism groups of finite graphs, these are quantum permutation groups. See also [this survey](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2402345) of Banica-Bichon-Collins.

Kojima proved [here](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=953960) that every finite group is realized as the full isometry group of some compact hyperbolic $3$-manifold. 
[This book](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3559897) of Goswami-Bhowmick introduces the notion of quantum isometry group.

**General question**: Is every finite quantum group a quantum symmetry group?

*Sub-question 1*: Is a finite quantum permutation group a twisted finite group?

*Sub-question 2*: Is every finite quantum group a quantum permutation group?
*Answer*: no, the smallest counter-example has dim. $24$ (see [this paper](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2900441) of Banica-Bichon-Natale).

*Sub-question 3*: Is every finite quantum permutation group of dimension $n$ a quantum permutation group of degree $n$?

*Sub-question 4*: Is every finite quantum permutation group a quantum automorphism group of a finite graph?

*Sub-question 5*: Is every finite quantum group $\mathbb{G}$ a quantum subgroup of the quantum automorphism group of a finite dimensional ${\rm C}^{\star}$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$? Ok for $\mathcal{A} = C(\mathbb{G})$?
*Answer* (Bhowmick): yes, it follows trivially from the definition, using Haar state.

*Sub-question 6*: Is every finite quantum group a quantum isometry group?

Comment: Small point: Kojima points out in his paper that his argument generalizes Greenberg's result on groups realizable as isometry groups of hyperbolic 2-manifolds.

Comment: Is *any* non trivial finite quantum permutation group a quantum automorphism group of a graph?

Comment: For question three there is no counter examples in duals of finite abelian groups as they all have two generators. If one has order $n$ it is cyclic otherwise both less than or equal $n/2$ and you can construct two Fourier-type magic unitaries and do block diagonal of those. Presumably no issue to push that to all group duals.

Comment: *finite SIMPLE groups not abelian groups.

Comment: No counterexamples to Q3 in group duals https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4007044/19352

Comment: @JPMcCarthy: Thanks for your investigation!

Comment: Is any non trivial finite quantum permutation group a quantum automorphism group of a graph? Yes: there is a dimension 256 example https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.12362

Comment: @JPMcCarthy: Good! I guess the question it answers is not "Is any..." but "Is there any...", right?

Comment: @Sebastien Palcoux yes, this is what I meant: "is there any?" rather than "Are all?" The answer below answers the second question.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to sub-question 4 is no.

See [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.04999.pdf), *The Frucht property in the quantum group setting*.

To expand slightly, this paper gives four explicit finite quantum permutation groups which are not the quantum automorphism groups of a finite graph: the duals of $S_3$, $A_4$, and $A_5$, and the Kac--Paljutkin quantum group of order eight, denoted $G_0$.

If the dual of $S_3$ is the quantum automorphism group of a graph, then, taking abelianisations, the (classical) automorphism group of the graph must be $\mathbb{Z}_2$. The paper above shows that if the dual of $S_3$ acts on a graph then a (classical) abelian group larger than $\mathbb{Z}_2$ acts on the graph too. Therefore the dual of $S_3$ is not the quantum automorphism group of a graph.

In fact it is shown that if the dual of $S_3$ acts on a graph then the dual of a(n infinite) free product acts on the graph too.

A similar story holds for the duals of $A_4$ and $A_5$.

If $G_0$ is the quantum automorphism group of a graph, then the graph has classical automorphism group $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. The above shows that if $G_0$ acts on a graph then so does the dihedral group of order eight. Therefore $G_0$ is not the quantum automorphism group of a graph.