# Is every permutation group on $n$ letters the symmetry group of a set of $n$ points in some euclidean space?

Tags: gr.group-theory, mg.metric-geometry

This question is superficially similar to a [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/993/2363). Suppose I am given a permutation group $G \subseteq S_n$. Is it always possible to find a set $X$ of $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that the isometry group of $X$ (together with its natural action on $X$) is equal to $G$ *as a permutation group*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No.  If $G$ is $2$-transitive $-$ or even transitive on pairs $-$ then
$X$ must be the set of vertices of a regular simplex,
which has isometry group $S_n$.  But there are plenty of
examples of $2$-transitive groups $G$ properly contained in $S_n$
(such as the $ax+b$ group if $n$ is a prime power and $n>3$).

Comment: Ah, of course. Even $\mathbb{Z}/3$ acting on itself is a counterexample!

Comment: Yes, that's the first example of an "$a^2 x + b$ group"
(for $n$ an prime power congruent to $3 \bmod 4$)
that is transitive on pairs $-$ even simply transitive on pairs $-$
but not quite 2-transitive.